# Setting specific zooms when clicking on different circle markers from the same layer in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, markers, zoom

I'm creating a Leaflet Map with circle markers designating specific plots of forest land across the U.S. When the user clicks on a marker, a popup shows up with information about the plot.  Since the plot locations are nationwide, but the plots themselves are small, I want the map to zoom into the area where the plot is located when the user clicks on the circle marker.

Ultimately, I have GeoJSON files of the spatial data for each plot, which I want to load and add to the map when the user clicks on the corresponding circle marker. Ideally, if I could get this zooming to work, I would specify a unique zoom level for each plot as well.

I've tried adding .on("click", function() {map.setZoom(10)}) to layer in the pointToLayer function, so overall it looks like this:

```
function pointToLayer(feature, latlng, attributes){
    var carboncredits = attributes[14];
    var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
        radius: 8,
        fillColor: "#B22222",
        color: "#000",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.8
    };
    var attValue = Number(feature.properties[carboncredits]);
    geojsonMarkerOptions.radius = calcPropRadius(attValue);
    var layer = L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    var popupContent = createPopupContent(feature.properties, carboncredits);
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {
        offset: new L.Point(0,-geojsonMarkerOptions.radius) 
    });
    layer.on('click', function() {
        map.setZoom(10);
    });
    return layer;
}
```

It gives me an error that says "Map.setZoom is not a function".

I'm not sure if it is correct to try to add the on click function to the pointToLayer function, since I ultimately would like to set a specific zoom level for each feature. If not, where should I be looking to add it?

Comment: Is it `map.getZoom` or `Map.getZoom` ?

Comment: If you map object is `map`, then `map.setZoom(10)` should work.

Comment: It's map.setZoom(10) with the lower case m, and the map object is "map", but map.setZoom(10) is not working.

Comment: In what way not working? Giving you error "map.setZoom is not a function"?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer was pretty silly. I just wasn't passing map as a parameter in the function, but it's all good and working now.  Sorry for the dumb question.